# i want redirect when user sellect seller it should go to the dashboard when user select buyer it go the homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here is my user model

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
 
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
enum role: { Buyer: 0, Seller: 0 } 
end
```

Here is the routes .

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
 
  root 'home#homepage'
  get 'dashboard', to: 'home#dashboard'
end
```

Here is my my registration form

```
    <h2>Sign up</h2>


<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.label :role %>
  <%= f.select :role, User.roles.keys %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up", data: {turbo: false} %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I don't know how to do it i trying so many method but it's not working for me. I want to do is when user select buyer it should go to the home page when user select seller it should go to the homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to do is create a `registrations_controller` and customize the `after_sign_up_path_for(resource` like so:

```rb
# app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
module Users
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    protected

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      # here you can check if the user is a buyer or seller and redirect to the correct path.
      if current_user.buyer?
        root_path
      else
        dashboard_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

After that you need to edit your routes so that devise will use this controller.

```rb
# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
```

Comment: not working i don't know why

Comment: Maybe you can tell what happens, are there any errors? What are the logs saying? Not working is not really helpfull.

Comment: no errors are found when i select buyer or seller in both cases they go to homepage

Comment: i run commang rails g devise : controller users . in the user i found registration controller file in the file i just paste this code..

Comment: Why did you do that? That's not part of my solution, so you can't say my solution is not working....

Comment: What are the logs in your terminal saying when you signup? Can you see to what controller it goes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242149/discussion-between-faheem-and-hackman).